# C++ passing reference to array to C function

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to call a function written in C which passes in a pointer to an array.

In C++ I have the following:

```
double* x = new double[10];

populateArray(x);
```

In C:

```
void populateArray(double* vars); 
{
    vars = (double*) malloc(10*sizeof(double));

    int i;

    for(i = 0; (i < 10); i++)
    {
        vars[i] = 1*20;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to output the contents of `x` inside the C++ code, the result is always 0?

Comment: No need to use `new` when calling. No need to allocate memory for the function's copy (let alone not free it), or cast the result of `malloc` when doing so.

Comment: @chris When not using `new` I get a segmentation error?

Comment: Then you're probably doing it wrong. The function doesn't do anything with what you pass in anyway.

Comment: Note that you're not passing a reference here, but a pointer. This does matter since C has no pass-by-reference, but C++ does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem arises because you are changing local variable `vars`.

Change to:

```
double* x; //you don't need to allocate here if you are allocating later

populateArray(&x);
```

And:

```
void populateArray(double** vars) 
{
    *vars = malloc(10*sizeof(double)); //also no need to cast malloc

    int i;

    for(i = 0; (i < 10); i++)
    {
        (*vars)[i] = 1*20;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the memory allocation here is done differently than in the other answers.
The function in this answer takes the address of a pointer that points to nothing, and makes it point to a new, initialized array. The functions in my and other answers take a pointer that already points to an array, and initialize the values in that space. Either way will solve your problem, but its good to be able to distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 0):

```
void populateArray(double* vars); 
{
    vars = (double*) malloc(10*sizeof(double)); // <---- remove this line completely
```

The problem is you're ignoring the `vars` you were given and creating a brand new buffer for it.

Worse, that buffer pointer gets lost when this function returns, causing a memory leak.

Just use the `vars` you were given -- delete the line indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Remove the `malloc` call inside the function.

Slightly longer answer:

You're changing the value of the `vals` pointer to *another* newly allocated memory -- thus, the argument you pass in gets unused (and thus is never populated).

The result being always 0 is a coincidence, it could be anything (or you could end up with [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)) because you're then reading uninitialized memory, which is undefined behavior.

This of it as this, if you remove the call:

```
vals = new double[10];
vals = malloc(10 * sizeof(double));
```

The first value is overwritten.